# I'm sending array of users from server file to controller. How to update array on controller if value increases on server side?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm using angularjs(HTML as engine) and expressjs to create a chat app. Now when any use joins I push him into array and pass that array to controller.js file. but it doesn't Update array over Controller File.

Any Hints/solution/advise are appreciated. And i'm a beginner to angular.js. As well using Socket.io.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: What exactly are you pushing into your array? The used socket? An User Object?

Comment: For example I joined the chat. Then I push Username into the array and send array to controller file using emit function.

Comment: Using angular, this is a miss usage. You'll have a more efficient software using services. Create a service to handle user connexion, then call myService.addUser(newUser), and make your controller watch on myService.users! The final solution should be a lot more testable!

Comment: @Nico Could you post more hint related to code.